# Looking for a Simple Way to Access and Export to a new array multiple data variables in an xarray object

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray object containing MODIS data imported from HDF4 format. The structure of the DataSet is something like the structure below where I have spectral bands in an array format stored within a Data Variable - each band is a different variable.

```
# Create example DataSet with 5 variables (let's pretend each layer is a band)
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {var: (("band", "x", "y"), np.random.rand(1, 10, 10)) for var in "abcde"}
)
```

If the bands were stored in an array, it would be easy to explore the data and plot each band using .plot and the built in facet  grid tools. However in this case i have to plot each layer individually or using a loop. Is there a quick  way to automate grabbing say x number of those variables or bands (maybe b,c and e as an example) and plotting them?

In some cases you may need to plot an RGB image - so i'd  do something like this:

```
# This is one way of combining  several bands into a single  array object however it's  very 
# manual. I need to specify each band in  the concat statement. But it does  achieve
# the output that I want using a manual approach.
new_object = xr.concat([ds.b,
             ds.c],
             ds.e,
             dim="band")

# Now I can plot the data
new_object.imshow.plot()
```

My goal is to automate the process of selecting x bands (or x number of data variables) for both  plotting / visualization and analysis. I don't want to hard code each  band into a `concat()` function as I did above. In the example above i wanted to plot an RGB image.  In other examples  i'd want visually explore  each band before addition processing OR just extract a few bands for other types of calculations & analysis.

Thank you for any direction!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`xarray.Dataset.to_array()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_array.html) may be what you are looking for.  For example for the RGB image I think something like the following would work:

```py
ds.squeeze("band").to_array(dim="band").sel(band=["b", "c", "e"]).plot.imshow()
```

You could also facet over the `"band"` dimension in that case:

```py
ds.squeeze("band").to_array(dim="band").plot(col="band")
```

Comment: @spencerclark my apologies for taking so  long to accept this. this answer  actually is  helping me with  several  different operations that i  was  going  about  using a more  complex approach!  thank you  so much!